# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number' can't be used to index type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting the error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number' 
can't be used to index type 'IStorage'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'IStorage'.
```

I see this issue in other posts but it doesn't make sense to my case. I have this interface below:

```
interface IStorage {
  id: number
  name: string
  vendor_id: string
  start_date: Date | null
  end_date: Date | null
  app: string
}
```

and this function:

```
handleSetStorageValues = (index: number) => (event: {
   name: string | number
   value: string | number
}) => {
   const storage = [...this.state.storage]
   storage[index][event.name] = event.value // --> error here at [event.name]
   this.setState(
     prevState => {
       return {
         ...prevState,
         storage,
       }
     }
   )
}
```

How do I specify the index signature type for this? `event.name` is referring to the name property that I am also getting from the `name` attribute on the input. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The proper type for a key that's gonna be used to access `IStorage` is `keyof IStorage`.

You may change the type for `event.name` to `keyof IStorage`. Something like this:

```
event: {
   name: keyof IStorage
   value: string | number
}
```

This will fix the read error, but you won't be able to write (assign) values.

You may think that you want to change the type for `event.value`. Something like this:

```
event: {
   name: keyof IStorage
   value: IStorage[keyof IStorage]
}
```

This won't work either, as now you do not match a `name` with a `value` so TS will complain as some combinations are not allowed.

Most likely you'll end up casting to `any` and taking the heat for the type checking.

`(storage[index] as any)[event.name] = event.value`

Probably the only type safe way of doing this is do manual checks for each property that can be a key of `IStorage` and the same for each value. This will become increasingly difficult as `IStorage` changes.